# The T on my keyboard auto's to caps

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard

When I use the <kbd>T</kbd> key on my keyboard, it capitalizes all and any letter keys that follow. This appeared after I had installed Wine on my Dell Inspiron 630m. Is there a fix?

Comment: Is it possible your keyboard layout has been altered in the localization/internationalization settings of the operating system?

Comment: What about numbers?

Comment: What model of keyboard?

Comment: Where does this happen? Just one application (which one)? All of them? In the GUI or on a direct console? Both?

Comment: richard, the problem seems only to affect the letter "T"

Comment: agc, tell me how to check for keyboard model (treat me as a newbie) I'll post the results...bosshogg

Comment: roaima, happens on all applications, I have to correct ALWAYS (AS YOU CAN SEE) after hitting the "T" KEY...bosshogg

Comment: This may be coincidence only, but this only started after downloading Wine, in an attempt to run Sketchup on Linuxmint

Comment: To all, the problems self corrected itself, now that worries me as much as the problem did it's self. Could this be a hard drive issue, I've bought an upgrade due to memory size and age of the old one, but recently have heard a noise coming from that area when I turn the laptop up (I rest my computer against the side of my settee,standing it up on the lock edge, as it were, when not on my lap)